# Measure of Dependence Between Two $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I got this problem from Shiryaev's book "Probability-1". I tried to use technique involving $\pi - \lambda$ system but I failed.

Let $\mathcal{F}_1, \mathcal{F}_2$ be two $\sigma$-algebras of subsets of the set $\Omega$. I want to prove

$$d(\mathcal{F}_1,\mathcal{F}_2)=4 \sup_{A_1 \in \mathcal{F}_1,A_2\in \mathcal{F}_2} |P(A_1 \cap A_2)-P(A_1)P(A_2)|$$

satisfies inequality $0\leq d(\mathcal{F}_1,\mathcal{F}_2) \leq 1$.

Comment: Could you explain what is $P$?

Comment: Probability of event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(A)P(B) =P(A)P(A\cap B)+P(A)P(B\setminus A) \leq P(A\cap B)+t(1-t)$ where  $t=P(A)$. An elementary Calculus argument shows that $t(1-t) \leq \frac 1 4$ for $t \in [0,1]$. Hence $P(A)P(B)-P(A\cap B) \leq \frac  1 4$. On the other hand $P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B) \leq \min \{P(A),P(B)\}-P(A)P(B) \leq \frac 1  4$ by the same Calculus argument. Combining these two we get $4|P(A)P(B)-P(A\cap B)| \leq 1$ for all $A$ and $B$.

EDIT: Instead of Calculus you can use simple algebra: $(2t-1)^{2} \geq 0$ so $t(1-t) \leq \frac 1  4$.

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice $P(A \cap B)\leq \min(P(A),P(B))$ can be used